# Getting a Meteor method to return a function?

Tags: meteor

I want to define a server-side Meteor method that, when called, will run a function on the client.

Ultra simple example below - I want this method to take a parameter, and when called, will run `console.log(parameter)` on the client side console.

```
Meteor.methods({

    consoleLogOnClient: function(text){
        var log = function(){ 
            console.log(text);
        };
        return log();
    }

});
```

But when I do:

```
Meteor.call('consoleLogOnClient', 'THIS MESSAGE SHOULD APPEAR ON THE CLIENT CONSOLE');
```

the message gets logged in the server console and nothing appears in the client console.

Ok, fair enough. Maybe I'll just return the function code itself and store that in a variable and then run it. But it doesn't work either.

```
Meteor.methods({

    consoleLogOnClient: function(text){
        var log = function(){ 
            console.log(text);
        };
        return log;
    }

});

var myFunction = Meteor.call('consoleLogOnClient', 'THIS MESSAGE SHOULD APPEAR ON THE CLIENT CONSOLE');

myFunction();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve a desired result with the [anticoders:client-call](http://atmospherejs.com/anticoders/client-call) package. It allows you to define client-side methods that you'd be able to run from the server side.

For example, if you define:

```
Meteor.ClientCall.methods({
  'consoleLog': function(message) {
    console.log(message);
  },
});
```

And set `userId` as `clientId` for the methods:

```
Deps.autorun(function() {
  Meteor.ClientCall.setClientId(Meteor.userId());
});
```

Then on the server side you can simply call:

```
Meteor.ClientCall.apply(userId, 'consoleLog', ['THIS MESSAGE SHOULD APPEAR IN THE CLIENT CONSOLE']);
```

Comment: Thanks! I checked out Client Call before now that I think about it. Mmmm... there doesn't seem to be much development activity around Client Call, so it made me a bit wary about depending on it for my projects. If Meteor updates and Client Call breaks, I'd be kind screwed, no?

Comment: As a developer of this package, I can assure you that it's not obsolete, there just wasn't a necessity to upgrade for some time. Plus it's rather simple, so if something breaks you shouldn't have trouble tweaking it yourself.

Comment: And to reassure: the necessity just arose, the package is now called `anticoders:client-call`.

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_methods

> They should return an EJSON-able value or throw an exception.

EJSON: http://docs.meteor.com/#ejson

So, the answer is that you can't send a function from the server to the client, since functions aren't EJSON values. But your real problem is probably that you want to send a function; I can't imagine why you want to do that. Send data instead.

Comment: Oh, I see. I guess it's a Meteor thing. I am working on some form validation stuff. Take for example a text field that can't be empty. Validating on the client is simple. But I also want to do the same validation on the server. And when that validation fails I wanted to return and automatically run a function with jQuery that, say, highlights a text box or something. Kinda like a shortcut.

Comment: If the validation on the client fails, run your jQuery function. If you validate everything on the client, your validation on the server doesn't need to return anything if the validation fails there, since it can only fail if the user hasn't used your validation on the client, which will never happened, unless the user is a hacker. Are you with me?